# Check Username Using Ajax in Jquery Validation Engine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, validation

I am using query Validation Engine :

http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

I want to validate the username field using ajax. If username already exisit in db.. It should validate.

Here is my code & something I have tried so far :

**JS:**

```
        "ajaxUserNameCheck": {
            "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
            // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
            "extraData": "name=eric",
            // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
            "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
            "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
            "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
        },
```

**HTML:**

```
<input class="validate[custom[ajaxUserNameCheck]" type="text" name="userName" id="userName" ></div>
```

It returns an error in alert:

```
jqv:custom type not allowed ajaxUserNameCheck
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <input class="validate[custom[ajaxUserNameCheck]" type="text" name="userName" id="userName" ><span id="emailinfo" ></span>

 $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#userName").focusout(function(){
     var e = $(this).val(); 
        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "username_validate.php", //AJAX FILE
            data: {e: e},
                    success: function(e)
                    { 
                        if(e == 0) 
                        {
                            $("#emailinfo").hide();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                        $("#emailinfo").html(e);
                        }
                    }               
                });

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
validate[custom[ajaxUserNameCheck]
```

with

```
validate[ajax[ajaxUserNameCheck]
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom rules are defined in jquery.validationEngine-en.js under section

CUSTOM RULES -- Those are specific to the demos, they can be removed or changed to your likings

Any modifications should be made there. Hope this helps.

Also you are missing a "]" close square brackets in your class=" syntax

class="validate[ajax[ajaxCaptchaCallPhp]]